# Build error: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIControl'

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14, uicontrol

I want to use one initializer or the other depending on the iOS version. If it is not iOS 14, I want to set the `action` to use later. My call to the super constructor happens inside an `if/else`:

```
class Control: UIControl {

    var action: (() -> Void)?

    init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let primaryAction = UIAction(handler: { _ in action() })
            super.init(frame: .zero, primaryAction: primaryAction)
        } else {
            super.init(frame: .zero)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

The call is:

```
let controlThatDoesNotWork = Control(action: { print("this doesn not work") })
```

The build error is

```
error: must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIControl'
    super.init(frame: .zero, primaryAction: primaryAction)
    ^
```

Any idea how I need to call this convenience initializer so it builds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `init(action: @escaping () -> Void)` is a designated initializer, and designated initializers are not allowed to call convenience initializers from the base class, they must call another designater initializer.

This is enforced [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID219):

> **Rule 1**
>     A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.

This the base initializer in discussion:

```swift
/// Initializes the control and adds primaryAction for the UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered control event. Subclasses of UIControl may alter or add behaviors around the usage of primaryAction, see subclass documentation of this initializer for additional information.
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
public convenience init(frame: CGRect, primaryAction: UIAction?)
```

So, you need to convert your initializer to a convenience one, and have to call with `self` instead of `super` the other intializers (again, due to the initializer rules):

```swift
class Control: UIControl {

    var action: (() -> Void)?

    convenience init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let primaryAction = UIAction(handler: { _ in action() })
            self.init(frame: .zero, primaryAction: primaryAction)
        } else {
            self.init(frame: .zero)
        }
        self.action = action
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

---

Alternatively, as adding a new subclass of `UIControl` will force all your custom classes to derive from that one, you could extend the `UIControl` with a new convenience initializer:

```swift
extension UIControl {
    // associated object dance to allow "stored" properties
    // in extensions and protocols over NSObject subclasses
    private static var primaryActionKey: UInt8 = 0
    private var primaryAction: (() -> Void)? {
        get {
            objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Self.primaryActionKey) as? () -> Void
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &Self.primaryActionKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
    
    convenience init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            let primaryAction = UIAction(handler: { _ in action() })
            self.init(frame: .zero, primaryAction: primaryAction)
        } else {
            self.init(frame: .zero)
            self.primaryAction = action
            addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPrimaryAction), for: .primaryActionTriggered)
        }
    }
    
    @objc private func onPrimaryAction() {
        primaryAction?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but regarding the last one, `addAction` is also only for iOS 14.

Comment: @regina_fallangi right, don't know how I missed that. Removed it from the question, and replaced it by another alternative.